# How to set default value for scope variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently display a scope variable using the following code

```
<a data-ng-href="#!/params/{{first.second.status}}">{{first.second.status}}</a>
```

Sometimes first.second.status is null, undefined or empty in which case I want to display "None" instead of actual value(empty)

One of the way to achieve the above is to put the check for the value of first.second.status in the controller and change its value accordingly but is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
<a ng-if="first.second.status" 
   data-ng-href="#!/params/{{first.second.status}}">{{first.second.status}}</a>
<span ng-if="!first.second.status">None</span>
```

Answer (score 14):

Just do:

```
{{first.second.status || "None"}}
```

Comment: I would also want to remove the href when it is None but have a valid one when it is not None. How do I do that?

Comment: Probably going to have to use a method to resolve the correct `href`

Comment: @raju Do you want to remove the href attribute or hide the entire element? If it's the latter, look at `ng-if` (as @MichaelLo just suggested) or even `ng-show/hide`.

Comment: I want to remove the href not hide the entire element.